# Wordpress - Footer not appearing on product pages

Tags: wordpress

I have a footer CTA widget (Best Quality Guarantee) that is appearing on all of the pages on my site, besides the shop and product archive pages.

How do I get it to appear on these pages as well?

The code for the widget is here -

```
<div>

<a class="best-quality-link" href="/best-quality-flowers"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Better.svg" alt="Best Quality Flowers" /></a>

<hr class="separator" />

</div>
```

You can see the Best Quality image on the bottom of this page - www.flowersforeveryone.co.za

But it doesn't appear on this page - https://flowersforeveryone.co.za/product-category/roses/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking at your source code on the archive page it shows that better.svg is definiteley there but it looks like your lazy-loading isn't triggering and displaying it as it still has the 'lazy-hidden' class attached to it. Try disabling lazy load and see if it appears. If it does, then try play with your lazy load plugin settings and if that fails try use a different plugin.